# Creating a record with a has_many through: relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble creating a record with a has_many through: relationship in Rails. I have a User model, a Task model and a Timer Model.  The idea is that a User `has_many :tasks` and also  `has_many :timers through: :tasks` Tasks also have many timers.  The idea is that a user can create as many tasks as they want and time themselves each day doing a specific task to track progress over time.

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :timers, through: :tasks

end
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :timers 


end
```

Timer.rb

```
class Timer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
end
```

The objective is that the user can see their tasks and start and stop a timer next to each task.  The timer is simple enough, it just has a date created and date modified that will track how long it ran.

However, in the timers_controller I'm not really sure how to create a timer:

```
class TimersController < ApplicationController

def new
  @timer = Timer.new
end

def create
  @timer = current_user.build(timer_params)
end

private
  def timer_params
    params.require(:timer).permit(:start_time)
  end
end
```

I've tried changing the structure of the create action as well as the params but so far nothing has worked.

For some additional context here is the tasks/index.html.erb

```
    <% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.title %>
  <%= form_for(@user.timers.build) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Start", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <% end %>
```

This is the Timer Migration:

```
class CreateTimers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :timers do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :task_id
      t.datetime :start_time
      t.datetime :end_time

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :timers, :user_id
    add_index :timers, :task_id

  end
end
```

Tasks migration:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but some ideas.

Joe Marion's answer can be right, if a task has only one timer. This seems reasonable, but it's not what you wrote (*Tasks also have many timers*). So here you have another option.

When you create the timer, it should be associated to a task (not directly to the user). And of course you need to know in advance which task the timer belongs to. The task_id should be a parameter in the form.

So the build command should be something like this

```
def create
  task = current_user.tasks.find_by(id: params[:task_id])
  if task
    @timer = task.timers.build(timer_params)
    if @timer.save
      # ....
    else
      # .....
  else
    # Error, task not found. Timer cannot be created
    # Whatever you want to do in this case ...
  end
end
```

In the view, your forms should be associated with tasks and should include the task_id to be used in the create action.

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.title %>
  <%= form_for(t.timers.build) do |f| %>
    <!-- where is the start_time field? -->
    <%= f.hidden_field :task_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Start", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean if a task has only one timer. The reason I didn't recommend a Timer model and went with a UserTasks table was because of the flexibility.  For instance with a UserTasks table you could time how long it takes to complete sections of the tasks and save them as separate entries to the UserTasks table.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. The difference is that in your model one task can have many users. Which models to use depends on the use cases the OP needs. If it’s hierarchical (users -> tasks -> timers where a timer belongs to a task that belongs to a user) or not (users and tasks, both independent and being related by users_taks (where you store the timer data).

Comment: Hey @Pablo thanks for your solution, I'm having trouble implementing it. I keep getting this error: `undefined local variable or method `task_id' for #<TimersController:0x007fbccdf99318> Did you mean? task ` when saving a new record (task) or if I put your create action in the timers_controller I get basically an identical message when trying to start a new timer.

Comment: Where do you get the error? (Which line of code exactly). task_id belongs to the Timer model (not TimersController). Timer belongs to Task, it should have a task_id. But it depends on your migrations. Can you add the migrations files? You must also add task_id as a permittted parameter in timer_params (I guess you already did it)

Comment: Hey @Pablo, I'm sorry I got sidetracked for a few weeks.  The error comes from the TimersController#Create method: `@timer = task.timer.build(timer_params)`  I will adjust my question to show the migration files.

Comment: it's @timer = task.timers.build (plural timers). Is this the problem?

Comment: This just changes the error to `undefined method "timers" for nil:NilClass`

Comment: This is because task is nil. It means the task was not found. I updated the answer. You must ensure the :task_id you pass in the params is a existing task.

Comment: Hey @Pablo, thank you for your patience, I think I am on the right track, but I'm a bit confused because I can't get the record to actually save. Generally the if statement in the create action is something like `if @timer.save` however your answer does not have that, so while I can get the action to "work" it dosen't save the record, it dosen't even seem to try.  I created a nested loop with the `if @timer.save` in it and then at least I get a "roll back transition" which makes it seem like it attempted to save although it was not successful.

Comment: Yes. @timer.save is missing in my answer :) It doesn't work if you save?

Comment: So there was a   `belongs_to :user` in the timer model that was causing problems, it saves now.  I think I was a little confused because I had refactored so much between my own experiments, your answer and @JoeMarion I just had a bunch of junk around.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Ahh, OK. Great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track how long each task takes you could just add a timer field to a user_tasks table.

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
end
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :users, through: :user_tasks
end
```

Timer.rb

```
class UserTasks < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The UserTasks is a join table that represents each individual task by the user. So if you added a time_to_complete field to the UserTasks table it would show the time for each task per user.

Comment: I'm having problems with creating new records now.  I believe I have created a UserTasks join table but any time I try to create a new task I get this error: `uninitialized constant User::Tasks`  I'm not sure how to write the         create action:  ` @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)`